# Mongoose Virtual Field One to Many

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have two models in my Mongo database, `Child` and `Parent`, for example. I will assign multiple children to a single parent. They are essentially defined as such:

```
childSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    // fields
});

parentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    // fields
    ones: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Child'
    }]
});
```

I have it working to where I can save multiple `Child`s to a single `Parent`, and everything saves and it all seems to be good there. You can also save each `Child` to multiple `Parent`s.

What I want is a virtual field on `Child` that is `parents`, and is populated with the `Parent`s to which it is assigned. This is complicated because each `Child` can have multiple `Parent`s, and each `Parent` can have multiple `Child`s assigned to it.

The route I took was:

```
childSchema.virtual('parents', {
    ref: 'Parent',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'children'
});
```

I have done this before with a store and its reviews, so one store has multiple reviews, so a Many to One relationship instead, and the above worked. However, with this, the `parents` virtual field always comes back null.

Is this the best way to do this? Or is there a better way that I should look into?

#### Edit

I realized I wasn't manually populating the virtual field, as I should have been, but when I tried to do that, it just makes the call for the child just hang and never comes back from the server.

My guess is that because the `Parent` model has the `children` attribute, it gets caught in an infinite loop, where it gets the child and populates the parents, which populate the children, which populate the parents....Is there any way to limit this?

Answer (score 5):

Actually this works just fine. You can of course define a link to multiple parents on the child as a virtual. A very common example of this is a "family", where all children have multiple parents.

I think you likely had this but forgot to define the schema options on the "child" schema where the "virtual" is defined:

```
{
  toJSON: { virtuals: true },
  toObject: { virtuals: true }
}
```

If you did not include those, the the "virtual" is not shown when you convert to JSON or Object.

Also, always set debugging `mongoose.set('debug', true)`. Where for example if you forgot to set the serialize options for "virtuals", then at least you would see the separate calls to the database being performed in order to fulfill the population.

As a full example:

```
const async = require('async'),
      mongoose = require('mongoose'),
      Schema = mongoose.Schema;


mongoose.set('debug',true);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/family');

const childSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
},{
  toJSON: { virtuals: true },
  toObject: { virtuals: true }
});

childSchema.virtual('parents', {
  ref: 'Parent',
  localField: '_id',
  foreignField: 'children'
});

const Child = mongoose.model('Child',childSchema);

const parentSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  title: String,
  children: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Child' }]
});

const Parent = mongoose.model('Parent',parentSchema);

function log(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2))
}

async.series(
  [
    (callback) =>
      async.each(mongoose.models,(model,callback) =>
        model.remove({},callback),callback),

    (callback) =>
      async.waterfall(
        [
          (callback) => Child.create(
            ['Bill','Ted'].map(name => ({ name })),callback),

          (children,callback) => Parent.create(
            [{ name: 'Jill', title: 'Mom'},{ name: 'Jack', title: 'Dad' }]
              .map( p => Object.assign(p, { children })),callback),

        ],
        callback
      ),

    (callback) =>
      Child.find()
        .populate({ path: 'parents', populate: { path: 'children' }})
        .exec((err,children) => {
        if (err) callback(err);
        log(children);
        callback()
      }),
  ],
  (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }
);
```

Which produces the expected output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "59575832c8af766505a55a24",
    "name": "Bill",
    "__v": 0,
    "parents": [
      {
        "_id": "59575832c8af766505a55a26",
        "name": "Jill",
        "title": "Mom",
        "__v": 0,
        "children": [
          {
            "_id": "59575832c8af766505a55a24",
            "name": "Bill",
            "__v": 0,
            "parents": null,
            "id": "59575832c8af766505a55a24"
          },
          {
            "_id": "59575832c8af766505a55a25",
            "name": "Ted",
            "__v": 0,
            "parents": null,
            "id": "59575832c8af766505a55a25"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "_id": "59575832c8af766505a55a27",
        "name": "Jack",
        "title": "Dad",
        "__v": 0,
        "children": [
          {
            "_id": "59575832c8af766505a55a24",
            "name": "Bill",
            "__v": 0,
            "parents": null,
            "id": "59575832c8af766505a55a24"
          },
          {
            "_id": "59575832c8af766505a55a25",
            "name": "Ted",
            "__v": 0,
            "parents": null,
            "id": "59575832c8af766505a55a25"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "id": "59575832c8af766505a55a24"
  },
  {
    "_id": "59575832c8af766505a55a25",
    "name": "Ted",
    "__v": 0,
    "parents": [
      {
        "_id": "59575832c8af766505a55a26",
        "name": "Jill",
        "title": "Mom",
        "__v": 0,
        "children": [
          {
            "_id": "59575832c8af766505a55a24",
            "name": "Bill",
            "__v": 0,
            "parents": null,
            "id": "59575832c8af766505a55a24"
          },
          {
            "_id": "59575832c8af766505a55a25",
            "name": "Ted",
            "__v": 0,
            "parents": null,
            "id": "59575832c8af766505a55a25"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "_id": "59575832c8af766505a55a27",
        "name": "Jack",
        "title": "Dad",
        "__v": 0,
        "children": [
          {
            "_id": "59575832c8af766505a55a24",
            "name": "Bill",
            "__v": 0,
            "parents": null,
            "id": "59575832c8af766505a55a24"
          },
          {
            "_id": "59575832c8af766505a55a25",
            "name": "Ted",
            "__v": 0,
            "parents": null,
            "id": "59575832c8af766505a55a25"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "id": "59575832c8af766505a55a25"
  }
]
```

Now I'm doing that as a nested population from the `Child` to get it's "virtual" `Parent`s and then even populate each `Parent`s "children". That's really as far as common sense takes me since we started at the child, it does not make sense to populate the "virtual" another time.

I will note on here that if you were expecting one of the following, then you have to consider these as "disclaimers" on the intended usage of "virtuals" in population:

1. If you don't want include the "children" as a real field in the parent. That simply is not possible, as their needs to be a reference on at least one side. The typical relation is Parent->Child where you avoid creating an array in the Parent and use the virtual. The other way around the Parent has "many" so you store the "many" references there, or alternately the "many" Parent references on the child. But there needs to be a list somewhere in the case of a "many" relation.
2. If you want an indefinite recursion here, then this is probably not the way to go about it. There are different ways you can model "tree structures", which generally involve keeping an array of the "materialized" path on each node, representing it's path back up the tree. That is really a whole subject on it's own, and out of the scope of population.

But in general, the concept works as designed. So as long as you understand how to work with it, then it certainly has it's own value.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I appreciate the help. This all makes sense, and helped me to understand a little better and fix my code. I found that the reason the call to get the child was never coming back from the server was that I had set all `find` and `findOne` calls to automatically populate on the Parent and Child models. So, when the Child was accessed, it populated the parents, which populated the children, which populated the parents...and so forth. It got caught in an infinite loop of population. I took out the auto populate and only call it when I need it, and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Neil Lunn goes into great depth to explain these relationships, and you should read that too while looking for an answer. In my case, here's the issue I had:

I found that the reason the call to get the child was never coming back from the server was that I had set all `find` and `findOne` calls to automatically populate on the Parent and Child models. So, when the Child was accessed, it populated the parents, which populated the children, which populated the parents...and so forth. It just got caught in an infinite loop of population. I took out the auto populate and only call it when I need it, and everything worked as expected.

Again, look at some of the other answers on here for sure, but this is why I was having issues, and someone else may be having the same problems.